Is there any way to retrieve back the source code from unstripped binary in Linux?
I was working on some C++ source code, unexpectedly I deleted the source code. But still I have my unstripped binary. Is there any way that I can retrieve my source code from the unstripped binary.
I can use ARM gdb but binary is cross compiled one so I cannot run the binary in my host machine. Also gdb not present for target.

Try objdump -S. I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532415/obtain-source-using-debugging-symbols answers your question. I think the answer is no. Consider deleted files disc recovery, and for the next time, consider backups and snapshoting (ex.I have btrfs with snapshots everyday).

Yes, of sorts.  I've used IDA Pro disassembler to recreate the source code from a binary.  It isn't cheap, but worth every penny (in my opinion).

But it won't "retrieve" your source code, it will "reverse-engineer" to give an equivalent source code that would output the given binary.

The technical term is "turning hamburger back into cows."  You can disassemble or decompile the binary to get code that's functionally equivalent to the original source (modulo any optimizations), but the original source is gone.  It doesn't help you now, but get into the habit of using version control tools like git.

No. Even an "unstripped" binary only has debugging information, but not the source code -- the debugger still takes that from the actual source file.
Learn using a revision control system such as git. If you put that on an external site such as github, you also have a great offsite backup...

Hmm by mistake I removed it before commit, I forgot only one file which is critical. Thanks for your response @Chrisitan Stieber
